# Room fallbackToDestructiveMigration with copy-pasted Pre-Populated Database

Tags: java, android, android-room, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack

My app has a pre-populated database which I update regularly. The user doesn't edit any of the data so migrations with `fallbackToDestructiveMigration` should work fine.

The problem is that I **copy-paste my DB from the assets folder to the database folder** of the app. So when I have to migrate to the new database. I can't copy paste the new file before building the database. The order I want to is:

1. use fallbackToDestructiveMigration (destroy the previous database)
2. copy paste the DB file
3. build

I can do this only if I use custom migration, but that will end up with too many migrations for each version making the code unnecessarily repetitive.

Here is my current code:

```
public synchronized static AppDatabase getInstance(final Context context, final AppExecutors executors) {
    if (sInstance == null) {
        synchronized (AppDatabase.class) {
            if (sInstance == null) {

                //DestructiveMigration and Build
                sInstance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, DATABASE_NAME)
                        .fallbackToDestructiveMigration().build();

                //Copy paste new db file
                copyAttachedDatabase(context.getApplicationContext(),DATABASE_NAME);

                sInstance.updateDatabaseCreated(context.getApplicationContext());
            }
        }
    }
    return sInstance;
}
```

I want to find a way to run fallbackToDestructiveMigration ->copy paste the DB file -> build.

Right now my code runs fallbackToDestructiveMigration -> build -> copy-paste DB file. This order won't load the DB file.